# Datalist ASP.Net. Only Show Gridlines of cells when populated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the datalist control on a page to display a list of data. I have the following options set which displays the data neatly in a table in four columns.

```
GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="4"
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" Width="300px" runat="server">
```

This works great when the list contains more than four items but when the list is less than four I get empty cells surrounded by the gridlines. What I would like to do is only show the gridlines on populated cells. Is there a solution using the datalist to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it dynamically when binding your DataList control like this:-

```
public void BindMyDataList()
{
    myDataList.DataSource = GetData();
    myDataList.DataBind();
    int count = GetData().Rows.Count; //Fetch the count
    myDataList.RepeatColumns = count < 4 ? count : 4;
}
```

You will have to change the code for retrieving `count` based on how you are fetching the data which you are binding to DataList.

This will display as many number of columns as you have total records to be binded else `4`.

Comment: great thanks..I'm using a datareader to return the data.. DataList1.DataSource = myDataReader;

Comment: @user552769 - You are welcome :) So I guess you were able to fetch the count?

Comment: Yes thanks Raul.. used this 
int count = 0;
                if (myDataReader.Read())
                {
                    count = (int)myDataReader["Rows"];
                }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
 <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label Visible='<%#bool.Parse((DataList1.Items.Count==0).ToString())%>' runat="server" ID="lblNoRecord" Text="No Record Found!"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
```